# Empty Dispose() method C#

Tags: c#

I have just started learning about IDisposable and Dispose(). I also read about the concept of unmanaged resources and several use cases on Dispose().

However, I have come across empty Dispose() methods in some of the source code I am studying. I have read all the posts on empty Dispose() on this forum but still do not understand it.

May I ask what is the purpose of having empty Dispose() method and why is this implemented in the first place?

**Code:**

```
public class Counter : IDisposable
{
    public double AverageCount { get { return Count.AverageCount; }}
    ...
    public readonly Counter Counter;
    internal ReadOnlyCounter(Counter counter)
    {
        Counter = counter;
    }
    
    public void Dispose() { }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this kind of code is suitable to studying? It could be a work in progress or a code from beginner. Without seeing "..." it looks like a wrapper, I guess there are two different `Counter` types. And it seems you have typo in getter.

Comment: @Sinatr Thank you for your reply. I am very new to c#. I was tasked to study some of the source codes by my employer and they are littered with empty Dispose(). Hence, I asked the question.

Comment: Do you have a colleague to ask questions? Ideally the author of above code or the one who supports it. They may have their reasons and while I expect to hear something like "oh, thanks for reporting, those indeed aren't needed", we don't know this 100%. It could be some weird tests what require certain types to implement `IDisposable`. It could be a bug. It could be a stub for codegeneration (functional programming?)... and I am not even trying hard to imagine.

Comment: @Sinatr Thank you for your advice. :) Yea, I should do that. Because I am new, I didnt want to ask them a seemingly trivial question that can be found on my own or from the community here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the example given, it serves no purpose whatsoever.

In some cases, an empty `Dispose()` is there because the type is being used in a polymorphic way, and *some types* that implement the same pattern might need disposal - `MemoryStream` being a good example of this (for many `Stream` types, disposal is necessary - so it is useful to enforce it at the base `Stream` type - but: `MemoryStream` doesn't have anything interesting to say here).

If the empty `Dispose()` method was `virtual`, it might make more sense - but again: that's getting back into polymorphism.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand now.

Answer (score 1):

One other reason to implement `IDisposable` would be to use the code in `using` blocks, which may make the business logic easier to read.

```
using(new Counter())
{
     // Some code relying on this counter
}
```

But since every reader would assume some code to be called on the closing bracket and be surprised that there is none, I do not known if it is a good reason.